# Determine possibilities where all elements in a list are present and in the same order as in another list

Tags: python, algorithm, subsequence

## The problem

e.g.

list1 = ["a", "c", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "b"]

list2 = ["a", "c", "a", "b"]

### Possibilities:

#### 1.

list1 = [**"a"**, **"c"**, "b", **"a"**, **"b"**, "c", "a", "c", "b"]

list2 = ["a", "c", "a", "b"]

those are indexes: [1, 2, 4, 5

#### 2.

list1 = [**"a"**, **"c"**, "b", **"a"**, "b", "c", "a", "c", **"b"**]

list2 = ["a", "c", "a", "b"]

those are indexes: [1, 2, 4, 9]

#### 3.

list1 = [**"a"**, **"c"**, "b", "a", "b", "c", **"a"**, "c", **"b"**]

list2 = ["a", "c", "a", "b"]

those are indexes: [1, 2, 7, 9]

#### 4.

list1 = [**"a"**, "c", "b", "a", "b", **"c"**, **"a"**, "c", **"b"**]

list2 = ["a", "c", "a", "b"]

those are indexes: [1, 6, 7, 9]

#### 5.

list1 = ["a", "c", "b", **"a"**, "b", **"c"**, **"a"**, "c", **"b"**]

list2 = ["a", "c", "a", "b"]

those are indexes: [4, 6, 7, 9]

## Output

The output should be an array of indexes never used

for that above example it would be
[2, 8]
(because it never appears in the indexes)

I tried a whole amount of solutions and all I could do is determine whether list2 is a subsequence of list1 or not

Comment: You're confusing your readers. List indexes start at 0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following python code does the job I think.  It is not necessarily optimal and uses only basic python capabilities.

```
target = [ "a", "c", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "b" ]
template = [ "a", "c", "a", "b" ]

def getEmbedded(target, relNdx, template):
    embeddeds = []
    if len(template) == 1:
        #  If the template list is only one element long, then check if any matches in the target list.
        for i in range(len(target)):
            if template[0] == target[i]:
                embeddeds.append([ relNdx + i ])
    else:
        # If the first element of the template matches an element in the target,
        #   then check if the remainder of the template is embedded in the remainder of the target.
        for i in range(len(target) - len(template)):
            if template[0] == target[i]:
                rtn = getEmbedded(target[i+1:], relNdx + i + 1, template[1:])
                for subSeq in rtn:
                    #  If any matches, then build up each match with were we are now.
                    embeddeds.append( [ relNdx + i ] + subSeq )
    return embeddeds

embeddeds = getEmbedded(target, 0, template)

usedNdxes = []
for i in range(len(target)):
    usedNdxes.append(False)
for embedded in embeddeds:
    for ndx in embedded:
        usedNdxes[ndx] = True
        
for i in range(len(usedNdxes)):
    if not usedNdxes[i]:
        print( i )
```

Answer (score 0):

I see I wrote a solution in parallel with petern0691, which seems to be very similar. I'll still add it for what its worth as it uses a bit more python libraries, like *list comprehension*, *sets*, etc.

I think the key for making an understandable solution for such problems is to use **recursive algorithm** as follows:

```py
target = ["a", "c", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "b"]
template = ["a", "c", "a", "b"]

solutions = []


def find_indices_in_list(list_in, start_index, value):
    if start_index>=len(list_in):
        return []
    return [i+start_index for i, val in enumerate(list_in[start_index:]) if val == value]


def find_pattern(target_index_stack, target_start_index):
    if (len(target_index_stack) == len(template)):
        # solution found
        solutions.append(target_index_stack)
        return
    template_index = len(target_index_stack)
    next_letter = template[template_index]

    matching_target_indices = find_indices_in_list(target, target_start_index, next_letter)
    for target_index in matching_target_indices:
        find_pattern(target_index_stack + [target_index], target_index+1)


find_pattern([],0)
print(solutions)

used_target_indices = set([target_index for solution in solutions for target_index in solution])
unused_target_indices = set(range(len(target))) - used_target_indices
print(unused_target_indices)
```

What happens above is that you chop your problem into pieces as follows:

1. find the first letter of the *template* within the *target* ('a')
2. for every occurrence of this letter in the *target*, you want to find the second letter of the *template* in the remainder of the *target*. 
    In other words, the remaining problem is the same as your main problem, but with only the last 3 letters of the *template* (`["c", "a", "b"]`), and with only the remaining part of your *target* (`["c", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "b"]` for the first occurrence).
   This is where the **recursion** comes into play: the `find_pattern()' function will call itself to solve the remainder of the solution.
3. You keep on recursing until one of the following occurs:

   - there is 'no template left', which means you have found a **solution**, you store it, and you go back
   - you are at the end of your target, and **no solution** was found on this path and you go back